# Bootstrap submenu hiding after click

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

Client of mine doesn't like the fact that Bootstrap's submenu hide right after the clicks which can be confusing for visitors using slow internet connection - menu item gets hidden, however requested page is not displayed (yet). They may try to click on the menu again and again.

Is there any way how to get the dropdown remain expanded at least until the next page does not start rendering? Thanks a lot.

Comment: But isn't that like the expected UI behavior? What about a loading popup instead? Or disabling the menu? Or some way of telling them "We received your click, don't click no more."

Comment: Good ideas, thanks, will definitely consider them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of a pure CSS or Bootstrap workaround, but you can stop the event from propagating further with some JavaScript:

```
$('.myMenu a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).parent().parent().html("Loading...");
});
```

That would remove the HTML from the dropdown and add a loading message.

http://www.bootply.com/FTBIkP9hfX

If all you want to do is just leave the menu opened, remove the second line:

```
$('.myMenu a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```